# Rails Receive HTTP POST Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a Rails app which receives a POST request from a NGINX Module. The request looks like as follows:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"asdadsasdads", "type"=>"live"}
```

I want to take the name and check in my Database if its the same, if yes I want to give a 200 back, if not 404.

```
def publish
  ssss = Ssss.find_by_name(params[:id])
  if ssss.name == params[:name]
    head 200, content_type: "text/html"
  else
    head 404, content_type: "text/html"
  end
end
```

This gives me a 500 Internal Server error.

If I remove the "ssss.name" and make a ":name" (I was just testing around) it gives me a 404. And if I remove the "head 404, content_type: "text/html" from the else statement it gives me 200, but then every request will pass through, even if it's not the same as in my DB.

I am not understanding how this even should work and I have a hard time googling. Can someone help me please? What would be correct?

Thanks!

Update 1:

```
def publish
  ssss = Ssss.find_by_name(params[:name])
  if ssss == params[:name]
    head 200, content_type: "text/html"
  else
    head 404, content_type: "text/html"
  end
end
```

That's what I am using right now. It gives me a 404 even though it should be fine?!

```
"name"=>"55b5807bbde1", "type"=>"live"}
Ssss Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ssss".* FROM "ssss" WHERE "ssss"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "55b5807bbde1"]]
```

If I change it to find(params[:id]), it gives me a 500

Comment: You're using `find_by_name`, but supplying it with `params[:id]`. Perhaps that would be a good place to start.

Comment: For searching by id use .find() or .find_by_id().

Comment: oh my god, I am so dumb... Ye, at least I dont get the 500 error. Now its 404, even though the names match: "name"=>"55b5807bbde1", "type"=>"live"}
  Ssss Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ssss".* FROM "ssss" WHERE "ssss"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "55b5807bbde1"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms) ........ Any idea?

Comment: How are you calling the `find_by_name` now?

Comment: find_by_name(params[:name]) and than I just use stream ==, if I use the ID I will get a 500 as well. With this solution I get a 404.

Comment: Can you update the code to show what you're currently using?

Comment: Ye sure, I've updated my first post.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your problem as of this writing is that you are storing an object of class `Ssss` in the variable `ssss`, then comparing this object to a `String`. This will return false because the objects are not of the same class, throwing you into the 404 block.

Try comparing `Ssss.name` to `params[:name]` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get 404 there as well :(     "name"=>"55b5807bbde1", "type"=>"live"}
  Ssss Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "ssss".* FROM "ssss" WHERE "ssss"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "55b5807bbde1"]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 12ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

Comment: What does your code for this conditional look like? And what is the class of `ssss.name`?